# D3. Can more then one element be associated with a single datum?

Tags: d3.js

The canonical D3 idiom looks like this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
```

This associates one datum with one element (`SGV`, `div`, whatever.). Is it possible to associate more then one element with a datum and then render them each in slightly different ways based on metadata associated with the single datum.

In my case I have a histogram `d3.layout.histogram`. Each histogram bin is an aggregate value composed of sub pieces. I want to render the aggregate then render the sub-pieces atop the aggregate.

I prefer not to create a separate histogram for each sub-piece.

Possible?

Comment: Are you describing a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#data)?  You histogram is bound to an array which contains both its data and a property that is an array for its "sub-pieces"?

Comment: Mark, you got it. Dude, that link is exactly what I am looking for. Pose your comment as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mark already mentioned in his comment, the desired behaviour can be achieved using [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#data).

The basic example by Mike Bostock is the following:

```
var matrix = [
  [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
  [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15],
];
var td = d3.selectAll("tbody tr")
  .data(matrix)
.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d, i) { return d; }); // d is matrix[i]
```

First you bind the data to your "parent elements", which are the `tr` in this example. Each element in the array `matrix` will be assigned to one `tr` element.

Inside the `tr`elements, you can select the sub-pieces and assign them the corresponding data by calling `data()` with a function as parameter.
This way inside of each `tr` there will be four `td` elements with the corresponding number assigned to it.

To actually append the elements and display the numbers inside a table, you would do the following:

```
var matrix = [
  [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
  [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15],
];
var table = d3.select("body").append("table");

var tr = table.selectAll("tr")
  .data(matrix)
.enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("td").text(function(d){return d;});
```